# Group by dayofweek not working with PostgreSQL (QueryDSL, joda.DateTime)

Tags: spring, postgresql, hsqldb, querydsl, dayofweek

I'm working on a project involving SpringBoot 1.5.8.RELEASE, JPA, QueryDSL 4.1.4 and HSQLDB 2.3.5.
I'm currently switching from HSQLDB to PostgreSQL 9.1-901-1.jdbc4. There were some errors with the queries, but i was able to fix them. On of them, however, I cannot fix.

I have a set of entities, marked with timestamp (joda.DateTime). I want to group them by `dayOfWeek` and get their count. The query looks like this:

```
JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager);
query.select(entity.time.dayOfWeek(), entity.count()).groupBy(entity.time.dayOfWeek());
query.where(...);
query.from(entity);
```

This worked fine formerly with HSQLDB, but no longer with PostgreSQL. Error looks like this (i replaced the actual entity name with `entity`):

```
2018-07-30 11:41:35,314 1892699 ERROR o.n.r.b.r.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler - Request (ServletWebRequest: uri=***) could not be handled. RuntimeException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
+-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
|  +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'dayofweek' {originalText=dayofweek}
|  \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
|     \-[DOT] DotNode: 'entity0_.time' {propertyName=time,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=time,path=entity.time,tableAlias=entity0_,className=.....Entity,classAlias=entity}
[...]
```

The query listed above with grouping by month, e.g

```
query.select(entity.time.month(), entity.count()).groupBy(entity.time.month());
```

works fine.

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
select dayofweek(entity.time), count(entity)
from Entity entity
where ...
group by dayofweek(entity.time)
```

Is that a problem with QueryDSL, DateTime and JPA? As far as i know, the keyword PostgreSQL expects for day of week is `dow` not `dayofweek`.
How to fix that?

EDIT: Same applies for group by `week`.

Comment: What type is `entity.time`?  `org.joda.time.DateTime` doesn't have a `month()` method. Maybe you have an old version of Joda that has this? Can you check what version of Joda you're running?

Comment: any workaround?